# Checking if a time frame matches a lists value in C#

Tags: c#, game-engine

I am trying to code a sort-of skybox system for my game. It will start getting dark at a certain time, and start getting light (after its got dark) at a certain time. What I am looking for is how can I check if the servers time is inbetween these time frames?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Game.GameEnvironment
{
    class GameEnvironmentHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// List of dark times.
        /// </summary>
        private List<string> _darkTimes;

        /// <summary>
        /// List of light times.
        /// </summary>
        private List<string> _lightTimes;

        public GameEnvironmentHandler()
        {
            // any time before 19:00 and after 08:00 is also light.

            _darkTimes = new List<string>
            {
                "19:00", // getting dark
                "19:30",
                "20:00",
                "20:30",
                "21:00" // fully dark
            };

            _lightTimes = new List<string>
            {
                "06:00", // getting light
                "06:30",
                "07:00",
                "07:30",
                "08:00" // fully light
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if its hit the first stage of dark times.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsGettingDark()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if its hit the first stage of light times.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsGettingLight()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets what stage of getting dark or light its at (1-5)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int GetTimeStage()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a `Timespan` as your storage mechanism

Comment: Timespan requires manually entering a time, you can't programatically load it from a list (not that I know of)

Comment: have a list of `Timespan`....

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide the hour of the present time:

```
int darkeningStart = 19;
int darkeningEnd = 21;

int brighteningStart = 6;
int brighteningEnd = 8;
```

[ ... ]

```
public bool IsGettingLight(int hour) 
{
   return (hour >= brighteningStart && hour < brighteningEnd);
}
```

Same thing goes for IsGettingDark().

You can implement stages if you can also provide the minute of the current time, but I don't know how your game is set up for that.